# I have used jquery for pagination in my code and javascript function to for selectall checkbox functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using javascript function for selectall checkbox functionality but this function is not working when i click next page. I am using jquery for pagination. I want if on first page i have 10 records and 10 on next page and so on,  then i select selectall checkbox on first page so it should select all the records on first page and all other pages records as well.

I am using apex in my code
Any help will be appreciated.

```
$ = jQuery.noConflict();
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.table').DataTable( {
                "searching":   false,
                "ordering": true,
                "info":     true


            } );
        } );




           function checkAll(cb)
            {
            var inputElem = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for(var i=0; i<inputElem.length; i++)
            {
            if(inputElem[i].id.indexOf("checkedone")!=-1)
            inputElem[i].checked = cb.checked;
            }
            }
```

Comment: please share your html also

Comment: i am not using HTML. I am using apex.

Comment: please mention this also in your question